# Python Fit Function (Could not convert float to string)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have this code to run a logistic regression on a data set. I keep getting this "could not convert string to float" error message. I'm not sure why that is because the column where this error is happening on is not a string. Can anyone help me figure out where I'm erring?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

#load data
names = ['user','query-executions','non-author-query-executions','query-writes', 'bi-object-view','table-view', 'query-view', 'catalog-edits','queries-run','searches','articles-written','curate-actions','flags-expanded','conversations-viewed','retention-week']
df = pd.read_csv('jupyter.csv', names=names)
X = array[:,1:12]
Y = array[:,13]
test = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=4)
fit = test.fit(X, Y)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'NONAUTHOR_EXECUTIONS'
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. I would recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

A value in your `X` matrix or `Y` matrix is `'NONAUTHOR_EXECUTIONS'`, you need to check all the values or its data type.

You can do the following:

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

another way

```
for col in df.columns:
    print(df[col].unique())
```

You need to make sure there are no string values in these.